# How to deal with UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
// vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const cookies_json_file = process.argv[2];
const url = process.argv[3];

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const cookiesString = await fs.readFile(cookies_json_file);
    const cookies = JSON.parse(cookiesString);
    await page.setCookie.apply(page, cookies);

    //await page.goto(url);
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    const content = await page.content();
    console.log(content);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

When I run the above code, I got the following error. Then it hangs there without terminating.

```
(node:50025) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/LifecycleWatcher.js:142:21
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:110:27)
    at Page.goto (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:629:49)
    at Page.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:23)
    at main.js:19:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
(node:50025) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:50025) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Although there are discussion about this message, I can not following it and can not figure out how to modify this code. Could anybody show me how to fix this code? Thanks.

https://thecodebarbarian.com/unhandled-promise-rejections-in-node.js.html

EDIT: here is the update code so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
// vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const cookies_json_file = process.argv[2];
const url = process.argv[3];

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const cookiesString = await fs.readFile(cookies_json_file);
    const cookies = JSON.parse(cookiesString);
    await page.setCookie.apply(page, cookies);

    try {
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
        const content = await page.content();
        console.log(content);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        process.exit(1);
    } finally {
        await browser.close();
    }
})();
```

Comment: The unhandled Promise rejection is just a cascading effect of the original error, *TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded*. That is the one you should really look into. Check what the `url` is, and if it looks as expected, double check that you can navigate to the url manually without timeout.

Comment: The first fix is to actually handle the rejection, e.g. by installing a `.catch()` on the AIIFE or wrapping the code in a `try`/`catch` block. The second fix is to prevent the `TimeoutError`, by using different timeout settings, the right url, or fixing the server bug.

Comment: The error only occurs infrequently. I can not figure out what is wrong with the server as the error is not always reproducible.

Comment: Not reproduceable? So what? Wrap in a try catch and log the error when it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently not a method to disable timeout's in puppeteer.
I suggest you add `{ timeout: 3000000 }` to your `page.goto` parameter.

Edit: I've found out that you wanted to catch the error, instead of decreasing the chances of the error happening.

This code should work

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
// vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const cookies_json_file = process.argv[2];
const url = process.argv[3];

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const cookiesString = await fs.readFile(cookies_json_file);
    const cookies = JSON.parse(cookiesString);
    await page.setCookie.apply(page, cookies);

    try {
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

        const content = await page.content();
        console.log(content);
        await browser.close();
    } catch (e) {console.log(e)}
})();
```

Comment: Why it is 3000000? Why not 30000? The warning message says `30000ms`.

Comment: The default timeout is 30 seconds. So you set it to 3000000 ms, which is 3000 seconds, to prevent a timeout error.

Comment: The program currently doesn't terminate. I do want it to terminate in 30 sec. Setting it to 3000000 will make it terminate after 3000 sec? This is too long to wait. How to terminate in 30 sec?

Comment: You should .catch it

Comment: Could you show me the modified code? I can't figure out how to change the code exactly?

Comment: After the change, why it says `TypeError: page.content is not a function`?

Comment: Instead of using ```.then``` and ```.catch```, try doing what you originally did, in a try catch.

Comment: Could you modify your answer accordingly? I am not sure I can change it correctly.

Comment: The `await browser.close();` probably should be in a `finally` clause

Comment: Could you show me how to modify the code to use `finally`? What is the difference between `finally` and `await`? I also want to get an error exit status. Will this code do so?

Comment: finally is after try and/or catch is done.

Example:

``try {
  tryCode - Block of code to try
}
catch(err) {
  catchCode - Block of code to handle errors
}
finally {
  finallyCode - Block of code to be executed regardless of the try / catch result
}``

Comment: See the update. Is `browser.close()` supposed to be called in `catch`